# Click on row table is not working when I use AJAX

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I have a very strange problem when I try to implement click on table row with AJAX. This is the JS code that I use for click on row:

```
//for tabs
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});

$(window).load(function() {
    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function (data) {
        if (data.status === "success") {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        }
    });
});

$("tr").not(':first').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlited');
    //                $(this).css("background","#707070");
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlited');
    //                $(this).css("background","");
    }
    );              

function highlight(param) {  
    var row = jQuery(param).parent().parent().children();
    row.toggleClass('highlited');
//                row.css("background","#707070");
}        

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (var i in inputs) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
        highlight(inputs[i]);
    }
}

//for clicking on a row and opening new page
function addOnclickToDatatableRows() {
    //gets all the generated rows in the html table
    var trs = document.getElementById('form:dataTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
    .getElementsByTagName('tr');
    //on every row, add onclick function (this is what you're looking for)
    for (var i = 0; trs.length > i; i++) {
        var cells = trs[i].cells;                    
        for(var j=1; j < cells.length; j++){
            cells[j].onclick = new Function("rowOnclick(this.parentElement)");
        }                    
    }
}

function rowOnclick(tr) {
    var elements = tr.cells[0].childNodes;
    for(var i = 0; elements.length > i; i++) {                           
        if ((typeof elements[i].id != "undefined") && (elements[i].id.indexOf("lnkHidden") > -1)) {
            //opne in a new window//  window.open(elements[i].href);
            location.href=elements[i].href
            break;
        }
    }                
    return false;
}
```

This is the JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>test</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="resources/css/themes/nvidia.com/images/favicon.ico" />
            <link href="resources/css/helper.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="resources/css/dropdown.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="resources/css/default.advanced.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
            <link href="resources/css/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/tabs.js"></script>          
    </h:head>
    <h:body onload="addOnclickToDatatableRows();">

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="DX-57" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Dashboard"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_sessions.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                    <h:form id="form">
                        <!-- The sortable data table -->

                        <h:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{SessionsController.dataList}" binding="#{table}" var="item">
                            <!-- Check box -->
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Select" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="highlight(this)" value="#{SessionsController.selectedIds[item.aSessionID]}" />
                                <!-- Click on table code -->  
                                <h:outputLink id="lnkHidden" value="HistoryLink.xhtml" style="display:none">
                                    <f:param name="id" value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
                                </h:outputLink>
                            </h:column>
                            <!-- Row number -->
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="№" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="№" value="№" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{table.rowIndex + SessionsController.firstRow + 1}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Account Session ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Account Session ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="User ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="User ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.userID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity Start Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity Start Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityStart}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity End Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity End Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityEnd}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activity}" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                        <!-- The paging buttons -->
                        <h:commandButton value="first" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>


                        <h:commandButton value="prev" action="#{SessionsController.pagePrevious}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <h:commandButton value="next" action="#{SessionsController.pageNext}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>    

                        <h:commandButton value="last" action="#{SessionsController.pageLast}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <h:outputText value="Page #{SessionsController.currentPage} / #{SessionsController.totalPages}" />
                        <br />

                        <!-- The paging links -->
                        <ui:repeat value="#{SessionsController.pages}" var="page">
                            <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{SessionsController.page}"
                                           rendered="#{page != SessionsController.currentPage}" >
                                <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>   
                            </h:commandLink>
                            <h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                          rendered="#{page == SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                        </ui:repeat>
                        <br />

                        <!-- Set rows per page -->
                        <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                        <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{SessionsController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                        <h:commandButton value="Set" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>
                        <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                        <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{SessionsController.deleteSelectedIDs}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <!--                        <a href="#" id="dialog_link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>Open Dialog</a>
                        -->
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/tabs.js"></script> 

                    </h:form>                  

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">

                </div>   
            </div>  
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

When I remove the AJAX code I can successfully click on datatable row and open a new page. But when I add the AJAX code when I load the table on the first page it works, but when I switch on the second page the JS code is not working. What maybe the problem?
I also call the JS code twice - in the header and at the end of the form.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/133242)

Comment: I think that I found the problem. This line `    <h:body onload="addOnclickToDatatableRows();">` must be insight the form not insight the body. But Netbeans shows me that the attribute `onload` is not supported into the `h:datatable` tag. What attribute is similar to `onload` and can be used in `h:datatable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onmouseover`.

```
<h:dataTable onmouseover="addOnclickToDatatableRows();">
```